# Simultaeous diagonalizability and the commutator

Tags: matrices

Is there any intuitive, down-to-earth, reason why the vanishing of the commutator $[ \ , \ ]$ of two operators $A$ and $B$, $[A,B] = 0$, implies simultaneous diagonalizability of $A$ and $B$, and why it is that this fails when $[A,B] \neq 0$?

Comment: Only true if one of $A,B$ are diagonalizable, otherwise, say $A$ is not diagonalizable, the $[A,A]=0$ but $A$ is not diagonalizable.

Comment: The key is that when $[A,B]=0$ they both must keep each others eigenspaces invariant. This allows you to reduce to the case when one of them is scalar. Also the restriction of a diagonalizable operator to an invariant subspace remains diagonalizable. The converse is clear. If $A$ and $B$ are simultaneously diagonalizable, then they commute.

Comment: Could you show in a bit more detail exactly how they keep the eigenspaces invariant, and what happen's when they don't - I see the intuition now but formulating the details... :( It's not even clear to me why they do this tbh

Comment: @ThomasAndrews You need *both* of them diagonalisable. Simultaneous diagonalisability implies that both matrices are diagonalisable in the first place! And $[I,B]=0$ for every (diagonalisable or non-diagonalisable) $B$.